# How to add manually written extension to Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, add-in, twebbrowser, chrome-web-driver

I have written a JavaScript, which i want to invoke in web page that is currently open in IE11.
Is there any way that i can invoke this JavaScript as extension to IE11 browser.

For example : In chrome i can easily do this by enabling the developer mode in chrome://extensions and click on LoadUnpackedExtensions and upload my project which is created by following the below mentioned link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-google-chrome-extension-in-visual-studio-2013/

In the same way I was not able to do for IE11.

Comment: IE11 or Firefox? They are different browsers...

Comment: I need solution for both the browsers.